# Trouble importing scanner class in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, import, java.util.scanner, importerror

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class vendingMachine {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int PENNIES_PER_DOLLAR = 100;
        final int PENNIES_PER_QUARTER = 25;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter the bill ($ 1 is 1 $5 is 5, etc. : ");
        int billValue = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Please enter the price of the desired item in pennies. : ");
        int itemPrice = in.nextInt();

        // computation of change due 
        int changeDue = (billValue * PENNIES_PER_DOLLAR) - itemPrice  ;
        int dollarsBack = changeDue / PENNIES_PER_DOLLAR ;
        changeDue = changeDue % PENNIES_PER_DOLLAR; 
        int quartersBack = changeDue / PENNIES_PER_DOLLAR;

        // print statements 

        System.out.printf("Dollars due back %6d" , dollarsBack);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.printf("Quarters due back %6d" , quartersBack);
        System.out.println(); 

    }

}
```

My error messages are:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
The constructor Scanner(InputStream) is undefined
The method nextInt() is undefined for the type Scanner
The method nextInt() is undefined for the type Scanner

at vendingMachine.main(vendingMachine.java:8)
```

I'm a coding newbie and Eclipse is the first IDE I have worked with, so I would appreciate it if you guys could help walk me through, resolving these errors.

Comment: Do you also have your own class named Scanner somewhere nearby? If so you could be confusing the compiler. I notice that the message does not call it `java.util.Scanner` but rather plain `Scanner` which is why I wonder about this.

Comment: What is the name with which you have saved this class? Are you sure you named it vendingMachine.java?

Comment: You must have made a class named Scanner, or some other naming error. Can you show us a picture of your package explorer structure?

Comment: Check your *Problems view* in Eclipse, and fix the compilation errors before executing the application

Comment: ............hello? Please don't abandon this question.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely you would have java file name `Scanner` somewhere in your project. Try

```
java.util.Scanner myScanner = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
```

instead. Else the compiler tries to instantiate your class which is also called Scanner.

Also, it's a good practice to start the name of class with Upper Case, it should be `VendingMachine` instead of `vendingMachine`.